# Why is one of my media queries not working?

Tags: css, media-queries, responsiveness

I have 3 stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 579px)" href="css/style-small.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 580px) and (max-width: 799px)" href="css/style-md.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Inside my `style.css` there is a media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:965px){
    //css styles
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine up to here. But then there is a media query inside my `style-md.css` file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:756px){
    nav.top-right{
        display: none;
    }

    blockquote{
        font-size: 1.35em;
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

And this is completely ignored. I can see the css code when using chrome's developer tools -> Sources. So it is not a matter of refreshing. Also, it is not a matter of precedence because when I do an "Inspect Element" on the target elements it would still show the code, only scratched; but it doesn't show it, it is just not there.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Use inspect element to go through those elements, and see if other styles are overriding your media query styles. Try using !important.

Comment: I used several files only because i'm trying to follow the "best practices" described in the google developers site. [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/how-to-choose-breakpoints?hl=en)

Comment: I did that already. The properties are not even listed when I inspect. The other styles defined in that same file, but NOT in the media query portion, work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I just had a similar problem and found out that I was missing a meta tag in the HEAD.

Adding this solved the issue:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Comment: 4 years later, still relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify that and only have one stylesheet file with those `media queries` inside, using the **non-mobile first method** approach:

```
@media only screen {
/*css styles*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 964px) {
/*css styles*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 799px) {
/*css styles*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 756px) {
/*css styles*/
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 579px) {
/*css styles*/
}
```

**EDIT**:
 (based on @Tony Barnes suggestion), you could also do the **mobile first approach**

would be something like this:

```css
@media only screen {
/*css styles*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 579px) {
/*css styles*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 756px) {
/*css styles*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 799px) {
/*css styles*/
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 964px) {
/*css styles*/
}
```

Comment: Why non-mobile first method?

Comment: because OP is using as first rule `max-width:579px` , so I tried not to mess with all the media queries OP had, just simplifying it.

Comment: Sure, but you could have pointed the OP into the direction of mobile first media queries :)

Comment: added your suggestion